# Preventing the app to terminate?

Tags: c#, ios, background, xamarin, terminate

I'm working with background tasks.

If I press the **home button once** **the app will call DidEnterBackground** and I can run anything here - Ok

If I press the **home button twice** and swipe the application out of the screen, finalizing it, **WillTerminate will be called** and after that, **the app DIED**, I can't do anything more.

On the Android I can do it and keep the app running, without show it on the android's app switcher.
There's a way to do it?

And how I re-open the app every time I kill the app (Every time WillTerminate is called).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot avoid the kill by the user. Apple philosophy is that the user is the "commander-in-chief" and he can decide to kill your app when he wants (and the kill must be real, no hidden processes).
All background tasks of the app will terminate with it and you cannot reverse the user decision (i.e. restarting automatically).

I don't see simple solution for your problem. The only thing that I can think is to put a big alert message to the user, when a specific task begins, saying:

*"don't kill this app from the switcher while this operation is running ..."*

or, save the state of the background process and restart it at the next run of the app.

Comment: So I can't develop the app... In the company where I work we are developing a personal safety application and the app had been waiting an external device gives a command over a network, if I it I can not do it . I'll have to stay with android version only

Comment: This is a big problem for me now... 
Can I do a process like remote notifications? When I touch a remote notification, the app open...
But I think this is with IPhone, I don't have access on it, right?

Comment: Yes, you can use remote notification (you need a real device for testing). Remember that if the user wants, he can disable remote notification for your app (but you can explain him that, in that case, your app became useless).

Comment: I have another idea... I can make an app like a Service? My external device communicates with IPhone via bluetooth... I can create a bluetooth service? I mean, create an app and a service... the app can be on background, Activated, killed and the service never is killed? This exist?
If yes, how?

Comment: No, I don't think. In iOS does not exist something like the "android service".

Comment: Thank you for your attention...I 'm screwed then. =D